# doxygen: include packet structure drawing in html documentation

Tags: doxygen, diagram, packet

I'm trying to include in my doxygen documentation (html) a drawing representing the structure of a packet, something similar to the following example:

[image: Packet structure drawing]

I know diagrams can be generated from code using several commands (e.g. `@startuml`/`@enduml`, `@dot`/`@enddot`, `@msc`/`@endmsc`), but looking at various usage examples I wasn't able to find a proper way of doing it.

Does anyone know how I can achieve a similar result without having to include an external resource, such as image or diagram file (using one of the commands above, or others if needed)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of doxygen did you use? In which format did you try to make your image, maybe the mentioned formats are not the best for drawing such a diagram and you should look at the possibilities to include directly an image (`\image` or in markdown image format or in html image definition) into the documentation. Please show some code of what you tried.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm using doxygen 1.8.13.
At the moment, I did not try to code something, so I don't have code to show. I just looked at those doxygen commands and I was wondering if any of those is suitable to achieve the result I want. In particular what I am interested in is to understand whether I can do it without including directly an image.

Comment: Maybe even a HTML table (with rowspan and colpan) might do in your case (doxygen will interpret most tables and use it also for other outputs like LaTeX)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If there is nothing more appropriate I'll go for a table. So, if I understand correctly, I can then code the table following these examples https://html.com/tables/rowspan-colspan/ inside the doxygen block `@htmlonly`/`@endhtmlonly`. Am I correct?

Comment: I think this will work and even better you probably won't even need the `@htmlonly/@endhtmlonly` as doxygen understands most table commands and translates some attributes for its own use (like `rowspan` and `colspan` and verbatim uses the uses attributes with the tags). I thin a good example can also be found in the doxygen manual: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/tables.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following albert suggestions, a HTML table seems the reasonable tool to achieve the result I was looking for.

Here is my attempt:

```html
<table style="border: none; border-collapse: collapse; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; table-layout: fixed; width: 1000px;">
 <caption style="caption-side: bottom" id="Figure-1">Example of binary string: IP packet structure.</caption>
 <tr>
  <td>
  <td style="text-align: left; font-size: 10px;" colspan="8">0
  <td style="text-align: left; font-size: 10px;" colspan="8">8
  <td style="text-align: left; font-size: 10px;" colspan="2">16
  <td style="text-align: right; font-size: 10px;" colspan="1">18
  <td style="text-align: left; font-size: 10px;" colspan="5">
  <td style="text-align: left; font-size: 10px;" colspan="4">24
  <td style="text-align: right; font-size: 10px;" colspan="4">31
 <tr>
  <td text-align="center" vertical-align="middle">1
  <td style="border: 2px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center;" colspan="4">Version
  <td style="border: 2px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center;" colspan="4">Header Length
  <td style="border: 2px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center;" colspan="8">Type of Service
  <td style="border: 2px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center;" colspan="16">Total Length
 <tr>
  <td text-align="center" vertical-align="middle">2
  <td style="border: 2px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center;" colspan="16">Identification
  <td style="border: 2px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center;" colspan="3">Flags
  <td style="border: 2px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center;" colspan="13">Fragment Offset
 <tr>
  <td text-align="center" vertical-align="middle">3
  <td style="border: 2px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center;" colspan="8">Time To Live
  <td style="border: 2px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center;" colspan="8">Protocol
  <td style="border: 2px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center;" colspan="16">Header Checksum
 <tr>
  <td text-align="center" vertical-align="middle">4
  <td style="border: 2px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center;" colspan="32">Source IP Address
 <tr>
  <td text-align="center" vertical-align="middle">5
  <td style="border: 2px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center;" colspan="32">Destination IP Address
 <tr>
  <td text-align="center" vertical-align="middle">6
  <td style="border: 2px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center;" colspan="32" rowspan="3">Options
 <tr>
  <td text-align="center" vertical-align="middle">7
 <tr>
  <td text-align="center" vertical-align="middle">8
</table>
```

Any other suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: For "Flags" I would indicate more clearly that it uses 3-bits

Comment: Something like adding another index in the first row at the position corresponding to the end of the field? (see edited snippet)

Comment: The idea is to have it corresponding with the other indices so at the beginning of the field i.e. the value 19 in this case. (Nice example, I tried it and got a small problem with LaTeX output, found the problem but have to see whether or not there are other corner cases).

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestions. I am interested in html output only for the time being, anyway